# facebook, how to get the facebook uid from any facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook, api

how to get the facebook uid off a page, when you visit that page?

if i go to a page of my friend or anybody, i need to know the uid. i can get mine like this:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$user_id = $signed_request['user_id'];
```

edit:
well i have this app and i need to pull the fakebook url into the application so i can grab the id from there.
 if i try, i get the app id:

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

what i need is to grab the fb link address,like @Rufinus said, something like `https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola`

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Can you clarify some stuff for me?

You want the UID of the viewing user?

Are they viewing the page wall or your app on a tab?

Have they authorised your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not 100% on what you're asking. It seems like you're definitely looking to get information about a page as opposed to a user.

If you have an app, on a page in a tab [like on the coke page](https://www.facebook.com/cocacola?sk=app_161193133389), then we'll pass you a signed request that contains the `id` of the `page`. You can then pass that to `https://graph.facebook.com/{ID}` and you'll get the same result as passing `https://graph.facebook.com/{vanityUrl}`.

What you want to access from the `signed_request` is `$signed_request['page']['id']`.

In that same page array, you can also pull `['page']['liked']` which will tell you if the viewer has liked the page. And finally you can access `['page']['admin']` which will tell you if the viewer is also an admin of that page.

If that doesn't answer your question, edit it a little more and i'll re-answer.

Comment: so what you are saying is that '$signed_request =  https://www.facebook.com/cocacola?sk=app_161193133389` . because what i need is just that. thanks

Comment: Well, if your app was on the Coca Cola page, then `$signed_request['page']['id']` would return `40796308305` which you can query the API with.

Answer (score 2):

you just can call https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola no token needed.

Comment: but how do i get that url? if i try `$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` i will get the app url